# Correct model to use for count data

Tags: regression, predictive-models, count-data

I've been working on an assignment for a while as a part of my final qualification thesis. I'll try to describe my problem in a nutshell. There is a small cable TV channell which sells some types of goods liks blenders, mops, etc. 24/7 they are broadcasting advertisments of the different products (the range is constant, 8 different products) of different duration (5, 10, 15, 20, 30 minutes). The fact of selling is assigned to this particular advertisment if the customer called after its beggining and before the next ad of this product. My task is to construct prediction function for the following broadcast optimization. I need to predict the number of orders for the given advertisment.

So, after countless attempts, I chose negative binomial regression to model this process. I have several predictors including interval before the start of the next ad of this product, set of dummy variables indicating products and durations, time of the day, number of this product ads (3 hours before this ad and 3 hours after) and so on. 
Is there any way to use more suitable model, for example, with fixed or random effects? As I understood, these methods were developed for the panel data but my set doesn't seem to be panel.

Thanks for your attention, any ideas would be appreciated.

P.S. There is a small sample of data, JIC

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B34-IapABY3mZllqOC1ZeWhWTkU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If you do not have panel structured data, you cannot use the estimators you've mentioned. It's a bit hard to see what your variables mean from just the spreadsheet, although panels in your case could maybe be different tv-stations, where the same adds are shown. Then you could possibly eliminate time-invariant tv-station-specific effects, if that's what you're after. Then you could get a more precise estimate of the variation in sales that are attributable to advertisement, and not differences in the people who watch different channels, that some viewers might  be more inclined to "buy stuff".

Comment: @hoyem thanks for your suggestions. it's the same TV station which advertizes the different products, so I can't classify different advertisments in this way